# How to get admin side base url in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, backend, base-url

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

echo $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();exit;
```

This only gives the frontend base URL. How to get admin side URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use following code directly in your phtml file to get admin URL.

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Backend\Helper\Data')->getHomePageUrl();
```

Comment: Used method 1 ,  but  i get the answer with multiple admin names....http://magento214new/admin/admin/.

Comment: Hello @DineshYadav your solution is fine to inject the helper inside constructor but we can also call the helper directly in PHTML file like `echo $this->helper('Magento\Backend\Helper\Data')->getHomePageUrl();`  is it not fine?

Comment: @SanchitGupta I have updated the answer. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->helper('Magento\Backend\Helper\Data')->getAreaFrontName(); // admin_7asd32
$this->helper('Magento\Backend\Helper\Data')->getHomePageUrl(); // http://magento.com/admin/admin
```

Note that this helper is only available on templates.

Answer (score 1):

In the corresponding Block, create a function:

```
public function getAdminUrl()
{
    $route = "admin/dashboard/index/";
    $params = [];
    return $this->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

In the corresponding phtml, echo it:

```
<?php echo $block->getAdminUrl(); ?>
```

---

**Notice**: The block should **extends** `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`